# Golang keeps old version in crypto/ssh/terminal.a

Tags: software-installation, apt

I'm currently trying to install version 1.4.2 of **Go** in my environment (Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit, Gnome, zsh). I'd like to run this program for [checking http2-status of domains](https://github.com/bradfitz/http2/tree/master/h2i).

---

I've installed the golang package via apt-get, which gave me version 1.2. Then I removed it with `apt-get purge` & `apt-get autoremove` and downloaded verson 1.4.2. Alright, but now this happens:

```
~/opt % go version
go version go1.4.2 linux/amd64
```

Then:

```
~/opt % go get github.com/bradfitz/http2/h2i
github.com/bradfitz/http2/h2i
../src/github.com/bradfitz/http2/h2i/h2i.go:41: import [~]/pkg/linux_amd64/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal.a: object is [linux amd64 go1.2.1 X:none] expected [linux amd64 go1.4.2 X:precisestack]
```

I have no idea, what this `terminal.a` file is about exactly, but there is that old line in it, indeed, which points to the older version of go. Does anybody have a hint? Should I just delete the `~/pkg/linux_amd64/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal.a` stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Sigh. Just delete the (probably old) ~/pkg folder and then try to fetch again:

`go get [antything]`

After doing that it worked for me.